# Add a column to data used with ggmap

Tags: r, shapefile, ggmap

I have a shape file of Statistical Local Areas (similar to postcode) in Australia.  You can download it [here](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.001July%202011?OpenDocument), the file is named "Statistical Local Areas ASGC Ed 2011 Digital Boundaries in ESRI Shapefile Format" (at time of writing, it's the second link).

I am trying to map the SLAs on a `ggmap` plot, using a Population field from a secondary table to provide the colour mapping.  Here's what I've got thus far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)

pops <- read_csv('http://mm-c.me/work/SlaPopulations.csv', col_types = "ci")

slas <- readOGR(dsn="SLA",layer="SLA11aAust")

aus4 <- get_map("Australia",zoom=4)
ggmap(aus4)

ggmap(aus4)+
  geom_path(data=slas, color = "black", aes(x=long,y=lat, group = group))

#Create a copy so we don't accidentally break the original
slasextended <- slas

slasextended@data <- slasextended@data %>% 
  left_join(pops)

#Throws an error 
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Population' not found
ggmap(aus4)+
  geom_polygon(data=slasextended, 
               color = "black", 
               aes(x = long, 
                   y = lat, 
                   group = group, 
                   fill = Population))
```

This approach is based on questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548372/adding-extra-data-column-to-shapefile-using-convert-to-shapefile-in-rs-shapefil), which suggest to treat the `@data` object as a data frame and then add columns to it.  The problem is that it seems like `ggmap` can't find the data to use for its display.

How do I do this?  Am I doing things entirely backward somehow or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ggplot2 tutorial](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles#preparation), spatial objects should be transformed to a data frame to work properly with ggplot:

```
slasextended@data <- slasextended@data %>% 
  left_join(pops)
slasextended@data$id <- rownames(slasextended@data)
slasextended.points <- fortify(slasextended, region = "id")
slasextended.df <- left_join(slasextended.points, 
    slasextended@data, by = "id")
```

The resulted standard data frame `slasextended.df` should be used for further plotting instead of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame `slasextended`:

```
test_plot <- ggmap(aus4) +
  geom_polygon(data = slasextended.df, 
               color = "black", 
               aes(
                    x = long, 
                    y = lat, 
                    group = group, 
                    fill = Population)
               ) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Greens", 
    na.value = "white")
```

Hope, it'll be helpful.